# Automate iOS application with Appium in Docker

Tags: docker, automation, automated-tests, appium

Is it possible to automate iOS applications with Appium in Docker with the Appium server running in a container?

Comment: I think that Calabash still have to installed Xcode for iOS testing, and I can't installed Xcode to container. or I miss something?

Comment: Please mention the OS and the environment you are using in your test setup or which you plan to use. Your question is incomplete.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu on Container (Docker). As i know container is not support OSX, so I can't install Xcode in container.

Comment: I already gave up...It's limitation of iOS automation

Comment: Curious, what did you end up doing instead? I'm also trying to automate iOS testing with Appium and it would be so nice to isolate it all in a container or at least a VM!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [appium-docker-ios](https://hub.docker.com/r/quamotion/appium-docker-ios) Docker image for this.

You'll need an Apple Developer account, a developer profile (with a provisioning profile and a developer certificate), and the developer disk images before you get started.

On your Linux machine, you need to:

- Install docker and usbmuxd
- Pair your iOS device with your host
- Copy your developer profile to `~/.quamotion/quamotion.developerprofile`, save the password to your developer profile in `~/.quamotion/quamotion.developerprofile.password` and save the developer disks to `/.quamotion/devimg`.

Then, you can start Appium using the following command:

```
docker run \
    -p 4723:4723 \
    -v /var/run/usbmuxd:/var/run/usbmuxd \
    -v ~/.quamotion/:/etc/quamotion/
    -e DEVELOPER_PROFILE_PASSWORD=1
    --name appium-docker-ios
    quamotion/appium-docker-ios
```

You should see the Appium server starting.

From here, you should be able to launch iOS automation just like you would on iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but it not an easy path.

1) You must have some Linux system with nested virtualization enabled(good for this Ubuntu 18.04);

2) To check that virtualization is supported - verify that `/dev/kvm` file is present:

```
$ ls -l /dev/kvm
crw-rw---- 1 root kvm 10, 232 мар  8 19:38 /dev/kvm
```

3) Qemu machine emulator installed. It is important to use the same qemu version on host machine where images are built and inside Docker image;

4) Download macOS installation image *remember you can’t up macOS in non-apple technique,* so you can use **[this](https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM)** hacking option(or some Hackintosh)

5) Install macOS image in a virtual machine (more about this in [link](https://github.com/aerokube/windows-images#build-procedure) *example for windows but you can do this for macOS*)

6) Install Xcode,appium, and add you app to macOS image

7) Creating Quick Boot Memory Snapshot (more about how in [link](https://github.com/aerokube/windows-images#4-creating-quick-boot-memory-snapshot))

8) Finally, build a docker image (more in [link](https://github.com/aerokube/windows-images#5-build-docker-image))

It experimental technic so a lot can go wrong, but this is the only working option I've heard about.